# R: how to resample a datetime variable at the millisecond level?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, xts, lubridate

I have a dataframe like the following

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
time = c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:23.559' )
value = c(1,2,3,4)

data <- data_frame(time, value)
data <-data %>%  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
                     time value
                   <dttm> <dbl>
1 2013-01-03 22:04:21.549     1
2 2013-01-03 22:04:21.549     2
3 2013-01-03 22:04:21.559     3
4 2013-01-03 22:04:23.559     4
```

I would like to resample this dataframe every 200 **milliseconds**.

That is, take the average of `value` every 200 milliseconds.

I know can use `lubridate::floor_date(time, '1 second')` up to the `second` precision, but not for `milliseconds`.

In the example above, row `1`,`2`, and `3` should be grouped together while row `4` should be alone (note it is `2` seconds apart from the others).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your comment to the xts solution asked for this to be "plugged back in" to the dataframe made me think you either wanted a merged result or a grouped-by-time column. That's what the `ave` function does in base R. There's probably a `dplyr` equivalent, but I'm more of a base-R-guy:
EDIT:

```
 data$ms200mn <- ave(data$value, 
                     cut( arg <- as.numeric(data$time) , 
                                breaks=seq( floor(arg[1]), ceil(arg[4]), by=0.2) ),
                     FUN=mean)
>  data
# A tibble: 4 × 3
                 time value ms200mn
               <dttm> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2013-01-03 22:04:21     1       2
2 2013-01-03 22:04:21     2       2
3 2013-01-03 22:04:21     3       2
4 2013-01-03 22:04:23     4       4
```

This isn't really properly called "sampling"  (or resampling), but is rather *aggregation*.  There is no 'msec' option for the `seq.POSIXt`-function (so needed to convert to numeric seconds) and fractional seconds are not allowed.

Explanation of:

```
cut(arg <- as.numeric(data$time), breaks=seq( floor(arg[1]), ceil(arg[4]), by=0.2) )
```

It is "classifying" or "categorizing" items in groups defined by a sequence of breaks starting below the first item and ending above the last item. The `arg`-value needed to be created because (for reasons that I don't understand) raw 'datetime' variables cannot be used can be used by the `seq` function.

Comment: thanks but I dont understand what is going on here: `ave(data$value, format(data$time, by= "3 sec"), FUN=mean)` gives the same result

Comment: That's because I thought my example proved that fractional seconds were acceptable. They aren't. I need to come up with a different 2nd argument to ave.

Comment: thanks mate. can you please explain what `cut( arg <as.numeric(data$time) ,  breaks=seq( floor(arg[1]), ceil(arg[4]), by=0.2) )` is doing?

Answer (score 3):

Since you used the `[xts]` tag, here's an xts solution:

```
options(digits.secs=6)
require(xts)
x <- xts(1:4, as.POSIXct(c('2013-01-03 22:04:21.549', '2013-01-03 22:04:21.549',
                           '2013-01-03 22:04:21.559', '2013-01-03 22:04:23.559')))
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "ms", 200), mean)
#                         [,1]
# 2013-01-03 22:04:21.559    2
# 2013-01-03 22:04:23.559    4
```

Starting from your `data` object:

```
x <- with(data, xts(value, time))
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "ms", 200), mean)
```

Comment: very clean! one difficulty here is that I need to groupby using dplyr (always the same reason.. i need to keep mixed variable types in the datafeame)  it is possible to plug back into the dataframe the grouping time variable constructed with xts?

Comment: Joshua, how would you adapt your solution starting from my dataframe? I mean, instead of creating your xts from scratch?

Comment: @Noobie: See my edit. It's not clear from your question how you need groupby using dplyr, so I can only guess at your use case. Also note that since `dplyr::lag` masks the `stats::lag` generic, you lose method dispatch at the top-level (i.e. calling `lag` on an xts object will not dispatch to `xts:::lag.xts`) if dplyr is attached. And I don't know what you mean by, "it is possible to plug back into the dataframe the grouping time variable constructed with xts?".

Comment: hi joshua, first of all happy new year. what i mean is: how can I use `xts::endpoints` to create a grouping variable `timegroup` in my dataframe so that I can perform groupby on that variable (thus grouping by groups if 200 milliseconds)? In essence, getting someting similar to the column `ms200mn` in the other answer.

Comment: @Noobie: You can't (easily). `xts::endpoints` is meant to be used with xts objects. And it only returns the end points of the time groups, not what would be needed for a grouping variable (one 'group' observation per raw observation).