# R - Group datetimes using cut at < 1 second intervals

Tags: r, datetime

In R, I am able to group data by datetimes using the `cut` function to divide the datetimes in time interval groups.

To create datetime data with fractions of seconds, this can be done with epoch timestamps like `as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201723886))`

Here is some toy data:

`times = c(as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201723886)), as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201724886)), as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201725886)), as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201726886)), as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201727886))),
as.POSIXct(nanotime::nanotime(1112089999201728886)))`

`x=c(5,6,7,8,9,10)`

`y=c('F','A','T','P','O','O')`

In tabular format:

```
data
# A tibble: 9,188 x 3
              datetime      x             y
                <dttm>  <dbl>         <chr>
 1 2000-12-31  5:00:00      5             F
 2 2000-12-31  5:00:00      6             A
 3 2000-12-31  5:00:00      7             T
 4 2000-12-31  5:00:00      8             P
 5 2000-12-31  5:00:00      9             O
 6 2000-12-31  5:00:00     10             O
```

For example this works:

`data %>% group_by(time_group=cut(datetime, "1 sec")) %>% summarise(count=n())`

However, if I want to group by a time interval smaller than one secone, like half a second, or one tenth of a second, or 50ms, I can't do it in the same way.

E.g. these throw errors:

`data %>% group_by(time_group=cut(datetime, "0.5 sec")) %>% summarise(count=n())`

`data %>% group_by(time_group=cut(datetime, "1 ms")) %>% summarise(count=n())`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402202/r-how-to-resample-a-datetime-variable-at-the-millisecond-level

Comment: @Masoud Thanks I will look into that. I guess then it is impossible with `dplyr` ....

Comment: You can use `dplyr` but still need to use `xts` or other methods that have been proposed there along with it. `dplyr` itself does not support what you need. Even your original solution for intervals larger than 1 second uses `cut` from `base`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your sub-second times to integers and calculate the # of breaks you want like so:

```
interval_in_secs <- 0.250
interval_in_secs_cut_breaks <- ( max(as.numeric(df$timestamp)) - min(as.numeric(df$timestamp)) ) / interval_in_secs
df %>%
  mutate(timestamp_ms_int = 1000*as.integer(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(timestamp = cut(timestamp_ms_int, interval_in_secs_cut_breaks))
```